# A question on Voisin's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I got stuck at some point in Voisin's book *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry II*. It is on page 58, proof of lemma 2.26:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb {CP}^{N}$ be a $n$-dimensional compact complex manifold, and $Y$ be a hyperplane section. Take any general hyperplane section $X_{\infty}$, set $B= Y\cap X_\infty$ and let $\tilde X$ be blow up of $X$ along the $B$. Then it claims
>   $$ker(H_{n-1}(Y)\to H_{n-1}(X))=ker(H_{n-1}(Y)\to H_{n-1}(\tilde X-X_\infty))$$

I want to know why this is true?
(On the book it says this followes from corollary 2.23 but I didn't see how)

**My attempt**

Since there is a map
$$\tilde X-X_\infty \hookrightarrow \tilde X \to X$$
we expect the composition induces the map on cohomology to be injective.

Meanwhile, corollary 2.23 says

$$H_{n-1}(\tilde X-X_\infty) \to H_{n-1}(\tilde X)$$
is injective. So only need to show the other map is injective. However, this seems not true. For instance, we can take $X=\mathbb{CP^3}$ and $\tilde X$ is blow up $\mathbb {CP^3}$ along a line. Then the blow down map will contract some $S^2$, hence the induced map on $H_2$ cannot be injective.

Comment: Shouldn't the kernel of $H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X})\to H_{n-1}(X)$ consist of classes which are contained in the exceptional divisor and therefore missed by the map you already know is injective? This would imply that the composite map is injective. Essentially what I'm suggesting is that the map $H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X})\to H_{n-1}(X)$ ought to be injective when restricted to the image of the map from $H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X}-X_\infty)$.

Comment: @KReiser This sounds reasonable. Could you please write it more formally as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: If a homology class $\alpha$ in $H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X})$ is has a representative supported on the exceptional divisor, then it's image is $0$ in $H_{n-1}(X)$ under the map induced by the blow-down. Furthermore, this is an equivalence: any class sent to $0$ under the map induced by the blow-down $Bl:\widetilde{X}\to X$ is has a representative contained in the exceptional divisor.

Proof: Suppose $\alpha$ has a representative supported on the exceptional divisor. Then the image of this representative is contained in a smaller-dimensional subvariety, and thus represents $0$ in $H_{n-1}(X)$. To show that this statement is an equivalence, suppose that $\beta\neq 0 \in H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X})$ does not have a representative supported on the exceptional divisor. Then $Bl_*(\beta)$ cannot have any representative contained in the closed subvariety we are blowing up, and therefore if $\beta$ was nonzero in $H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X})$, it must be nonzero in $H_{n-1}(X)$.

In particular, this shows that any nonzero class in the image of $H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X}-X_\infty)\hookrightarrow H_{n-1}(\widetilde{X})$ cannot be sent to $0$ under the composite map: any such class cannot have a representative contained in the exceptional divisor. Therefore the composite map is injective, and combined with the work in your post, this proves the statement.